# Phalcon Micro app doesn't route correctly with query strings

Tags: routes, query-string, phalcon, php-builtin-server

I'm trying to develop a RESTful API with a **Micro** app in **Phalcon**. Now I'm working in the social login with the Facebook SDK for PHP, but I find that when Facebook redirects me to my callback (with a **query string inside** obviously) the router doesn't find any handler method.

```
GET: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/register/facebook/callback?code=...&state=...#_=_

Not-Found handler is not callable or is not defined
#0 /home/adrian/PhpstormProjects/myproject/index.php(39): Phalcon\Mvc\Micro->handle()
#1 {main}
```

All my other routes work properly, but this is the first time I face query strings so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

I'm using **Micro Collections** for routing and the PHP **built-in server**.

This is my `.htrouter.php`. When **I suppress** the query string from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` the **route works** correctly, but the Facebook SDK fails because it's expecting the parameters. I've tried to find if Phalcon saves the URL and the query string in different `$_GET` variables, but I think it's not the case.

```
<?php
if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $_GET['_url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
return false;
```

My `micro-collection.php`

```
<?php

use \Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\Collection as MicroCollection;

$register = new MicroCollection();
$register->setHandler('App\Controllers\V1\RegisterController', true);
$register->setPrefix('/api/v1/register');
$register->get('/facebook', 'getAuthFacebook');
$register->get('/facebook/callback', 'facebookCallback');

return $register;
```

This is my `RegisterController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\V1;

use App\Controllers\ControllerBase;
use Phalcon\Http\Response;

class RegisterController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function getAuthFacebook()
    {
        $helper = $this->facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        $permissions = ['email', 'user_likes'];
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/register/facebook/callback', $permissions);

        return new Response($loginUrl);
    }

    public function facebookCallback()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

My `index.php` is exactly the same as the one that `phalcon-devtools` generates for a new project except that I mount my micro collections, so I think that the problem is not there.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When there is no query string your route (http://localhost:8000/api/v1/register/facebook/callback) works correctly ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, after a lot of research by the forums I've found the solution. I had to add this to my `index.php`:

Just after:

```
$app = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Micro($di);
```

This:

```
$app->getRouter()->setUriSource(\Phalcon\Mvc\Router::URI_SOURCE_SERVER_REQUEST_URI);
```

[Source](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/4527/phalcon-rest-api-problem)

I don't know why it works, because as the [documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/es/latest/reference/routing.html#uri-sources) says, it changes the router behaviour in order to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `$_GET['_url']` but that's actually what `.htrouter.php` does (or at least try to do).

Anyways, as I'm not very experienced with Phalcon, it's very likely that I've misunderstood something. Hope it helps.

Comment: In https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/router.zep#L168 you can see that when using SERVER_REQUEST_URI it does a split on ? to extract only the path. When using GET_URL you don't do this process. I don't know why this diff exists but it changes behavior between the URL source

Comment: by the time phalcon 2.0.13, Jul 2016 , just experienced this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Making my own implementation of a micro app, i did found that php version affects the behavior of the request url parsing. On php 5.6 i had to use the answer by @soutoner

For a request [/service/endpoint?somefilter=something](http://example.com)

> `$app->getRouter()->setUriSource(\Phalcon\Mvc\Router::URI_SOURCE_SERVER_REQUEST_URI);`

Without this dumping the request shows params as `endpoint?somefilter=something`

On php 7 dumps shows `endpoint` which is perfect

Interesting thing is that adding this doesn't brake the app on php 7 and makes the fix for php 5.6. So its a good tip for retro compatibility. Didn't tested on 7.2 but i suppose it would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check that the `/facebook/callback` works correctly or not?
This url : [/facebook/callback](http://localhost:8000/api/v1/register/facebook/callback)
Then in your function use `getQuery` method :

```
public function facebookCallback() {
   if($this->request->getQuery('code') !== null) {
        $code = $this->request->getQuery('code');
        // your other codes here
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've already tried removing the query string from urls, and all of them (which ones I've tried with) work correctly. The problem of the code that you suggest me is that if I remove the query string, the `code` parameter is inexistent so I never reach the condition. If I put again the query string, the router misbehaves.

Comment: After a lot of research I've found a fix for the problem. Thank you so much for your help anyway!